# In SQL, how do I select unique user id when it may have two different observations?

Tags: sql, unique, union

I have a table that contains Persons Name and Country of Citizenship. A person may have a dual citizenship, but if they have US citizenship, I just want that row for the person.

Ex:\

```
Name   Citizenship\
John       US\
John      England\
Jim       Germany\
Mark      US\
Mark      Belgium
```

Expected Output

```
Name    Country\
John     US\
Jim      Germany\
Mark     US
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Which database and version are you using, please?

Comment: Its in Teradata. I believe the latest version

Comment: And what do you want to show if they have multiple citizenships but none of them are the US?

Comment: In this particular case, there are no such people.

Comment: Is this homework? That's ok, it just changes how I'd answer.

Comment: Quibble: England isn't a citizenship. :) John would be a citizen of the UK.

Comment: No. the actual problem is a bit different, but this example is the gist of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.citizenship = 'US'
or not exists (select 1 from tablename where name = t.name and citizenship = 'US')
```

or with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
select distinct name,
       first_value(citizenship) 
       over (partition by name order by case when citizenship = 'US' then 1 else 2 end) citizenship
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09b60764ff2a2354eafe863378d488ed).
Results:

```
> Name | Citizenship
> :--- | :----------
> John | US         
> Jim  | Germany    
> Mark | US
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select name, citizenship,
    row_number() over(partition by name 
      order by case when citizenship = 'US' then 1 else 2 end, citizenship
    ) as rn
  from t 
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is the best approach.  It guarantees one row per person.  I know people with three passports.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one flavor:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name,
    Citizenship= CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Citizenship = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) > 1 THEN 'US' ELSE Citizenship END
FROM 
    t
```